# Agregar columnas en dataframe con pandas y python

Tags: python, pandas

Necesito agregar una columna, la cual me diga el idioma según el país.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfs=pd.read_html("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Sencillos_n%C3%BAmero_uno_en_Espa%C3%B1a#Canciones_con_m%C3%A1s_semanas_en_el_n%C3%BAmero_uno")[1]

dfs.head()
print("Los datos de Canciones con más semanas en el número uno son", len(dfs),"Canciones:")

def idioma(País):
  if País =="Colombia":
    ("Español")
  continente=str("America")
  return pd.Series([idioma])

dfs[['Idioma']]=dfs['País'].apply(idioma)
dfs
```

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El problema está en la forma en como estás utilizando el [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Cuando utilizas `apply` en una serie (Es decir, en una columna) como `dfs['País']` entonces el argumento que se enviará a la función es la "celda". Cuando utilizas `apply` directamente en el `dataframe` el argumento será toda la fila o toda la columna, dependiendo del eje (Argument `axis`) que utilices (Revisa la documentación).

Ahora, cuando el país es "Colombia" deberías regresar (Utilizando `return`) "Español" ya que el valor del retorno debe ser el valor para una "celda" de tu serie y no una serie completa como estás intentando hacerlo.

**Nota:** Es recomendable nombrar las variables únicamente con caracteres que se utilicen en el idioma inglés. Lectura recomendada [PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

**Tip:** podrías crear listas o un diccionario para asignar varios países a un idioma y no tener que utilizar un montón de `if`.

Ejemplo con listas (No todos los países han sido agregados a las listas para que veas el funcionamiento):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfs=pd.read_html("https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Sencillos_n%C3%BAmero_uno_en_Espa%C3%B1a#Canciones_con_m%C3%A1s_semanas_en_el_n%C3%BAmero_uno")[1]

print(f'Los datos de canciones con más semanas en el número uno son, {len(dfs)} canciones:')

def idioma(pais):
    hispanos = ['Colombia', 'Venezuela', 'Puerto Rico']
    anglosajones = ['Estados Unidos']
    
    if pais in hispanos:
        return 'Español'
    elif pais in anglosajones:
        return 'Inglés'
    else:
        return 'No se ha configurado'

dfs['Idioma'] = dfs['País'].apply(idioma)
print(dfs)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
                                     Tema  \
0                   Colgando en tus manos   
1                               Despacito   
2            "You're the One That I Want"   
3                                Bailando   
4                               El Perdón   
5                                   Sorry   
6              Waka Waka (Esto es África)   
7                                    Tusa   
8                      Gimme Hope Jo'anna   
9                            On the Floor   
10                         Voyage, Voyage   
11                         Yo Te Esperaré   
12                       Ai Se Eu Te Pego   
13                     Candle in the wind   
14  Quevedo: BZRP Music Sessions, Vol. 52   
15                           La Bicicleta   
16                                Lambada   
17                       Duele El Corazón   
18                            Mambo No. 5   
19                                   Loca   
20                      Always on My Mind   
21                            La Gozadera   
22                               Infinity   
23                       Te Voy A Esperar   
24                    The Final Countdown   

                                           Intérprete        Año  Semanas  \
0                      Carlos Baute con Marta Sánchez       2009       27   
1                           Luis Fonsi y Daddy Yankee       2017       26   
2                  John Travolta & Olivia Newton-John  1978/1991       20   
3   Enrique Iglesias con Descemer Bueno y Gente de...       2014       20   
4                        Enrique Iglesias y Nicky Jam       2015       18   
5                                       Justin Bieber       2015       17   
6                                             Shakira       2010       17   
7                               Karol G y Nicki Minaj       2019       16   
8                                          Eddy Grant       1988       15   
9                            Jennifer López y Pitbull       2011       15   
10                                         Desireless       1987       15   
11                                   Cali y El Dandee       2012       15   
12                                        Michel Teló       2011       14   
13                                         Elton John       1987       14   
14                                 Bizarrap y Quevedo       2022       13   
15                             Carlos Vives y Shakira       2016       13   
16                                              Kaoma       1989       13   
17                           Enrique Iglesias y Wisin       2016       12   
18                                           Lou Bega       1999       12   
19                                            Shakira       2010       12   
20                                      Pet Shop Boys       1988       11   
21                       Gente de Zona y Marc Anthony       2015       11   
22                                          Guru Josh       1990       10   
23                               Juan Magán y Belinda       2012       10   
24                                             Europe       1987       10   

                          País                Idioma  
0                    Venezuela               Español  
1                  Puerto Rico               Español  
2               Estados Unidos                Inglés  
3                       España  No se ha configurado  
4                       España  No se ha configurado  
5                       Canadá  No se ha configurado  
6                     Colombia               Español  
7   Colombia Trinidad y Tobago  No se ha configurado  
8                       Guyana  No se ha configurado  
9               Estados Unidos                Inglés  
10                     Francia  No se ha configurado  
11                    Colombia               Español  
12                      Brasil  No se ha configurado  
13                 Reino Unido  No se ha configurado  
14            Argentina España  No se ha configurado  
15                    Colombia               Español  
16                      Brasil  No se ha configurado  
17                      España  No se ha configurado  
18                    Alemania  No se ha configurado  
19                    Colombia               Español  
20                 Reino Unido  No se ha configurado  
21                        Cuba  No se ha configurado  
22                 Reino Unido  No se ha configurado  
23                      España  No se ha configurado  
24                      Suecia  No se ha configurado
```